# Specify to call someting when main thread is idle

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, xcode

Say I have a low priority job. Like checking queues whether there are URL to grab, or stuff.

How can I do that?

I can use timer to check every seconds but I am sure there are better ways.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use GCD to schedule a task with low priority in the main queue.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
      //Your code here
});
```

You can put this code within a loop, timer or whatever you want.

Comment: I already figured this one out. That will actually do the stuff at the same time rather than when computer is idle except that at lower priority.

Comment: This will not actually run on the main thread, but on a background queue. I'm looking for a way to schedule something that must be run on the main thread, but preferable when it is idle.